# Stalling operations in doInBackground AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am just trying to keep the application in sleep mode during the `doInBackground()` of the `AsyncTask`. For that very reason I tried using a thread inside `doInBackground()`

```
protected String doInBackground(String... input) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
    return null;
}
```

The thread in my guess is being executed as a separately ?? Because the `onPostExecute()` is called right after ignoring the delay that I put.

Can someone suggest something so that I could delay the call to `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Thread.sleep(3000)` in `doInBackground` in place of the `Thread` you are using. This will put the `AsyncTask` to sleep for 3 seconds.

Comment: could you explain why this worked? ... and thanks :)

Comment: AsyncTask is a convenience class for doing some work on a new thread and use the results on the thread from which it got called (usually the UI thread) when finished. It's just a wrapper which uses a couple of runnables but handles all the intricacies of creating the thread and handling messaging between the threads. What you were doing created started another `Thread` within the `AsyncTask` which ran independent of it and hence it did not go to sleep.